# SUM(if) function for multiple criteria + date/time that is dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2013, array-formulas

I got a problem to "extend" my formula to make correct calculation, in my case `SUM()` of **!Time difference in Column G** OR **!% of time in `Column H`** using criteria in **!System in `Column K`** in certain **!date `Column C`**. 
So, as you can notice there are couple of events per one day  and with its given **!time `Column E`** (for instance 2019-01-10 has 5 events, but the number isnt always the same).

What I actually wanted is to `SUM()` partially how many (total time per day) of ST and SC (from System Column) are contained per one day, and how to solve that with changeable Date/Time? I mean, manually will take me forever, because I have like over 1000 such a events, and I wanted to make it per day if its possible, or do you guys got any other suggest??

The goal is to calculate utilization rate per one day for both System types.

I used simple `=SUMIF` as you can see on L2, but I am pretty sure it has to be combined with way more functions and criterias..

I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: So have a look at SUMIFS() or use an IF() to put a 1 if all the conditions are met for each row and then sumproduct()...

Comment: Why not use a helper column to get you `True` or `False` result for summing?

Comment: Helper: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4319-excel-rank-by-group.html

Comment: To notice, Time Difference in Column G is actually calculated using =mod (c2-c1), so using helper and ranking is making it wrong. In Column E is exact time during the day, and that has to be exactly in the same order as it is calculate (column G), I mean I do not get it, i am looking everywhere and still I am on 0 point, okay, at least I can do that manually what is not my goal.

Comment: I think your case can be simply solved by using **SUMIFS** function as suggested by @SolarMike. In your case there are two criteria. one is the date and the other is the system. SUMIF cannot handle more than one criteria but SUMIF**S** can. Try google how to use this function online and let me know if you still want to see a proper solution posted here for you.

Comment: Hey! @Mirza do u want result based on Day wise by these two criteria ST&SC? If yes i have an idea for it !

Comment: As some have said the best solution is to use sumifs like this: =SUMIFS($G:$G,$K:$K,L$1,$C:$C,$C2)

Comment: @Regiz hi!  yea, actually that is an idea, to have one result for ST and another for SC per day!!

Comment: @TerryW I understand it...but what gives me trouble is this Date(s) value, same instances (2019-01-10 like 5 times) but still different time. I will look a bit more...

Comment: @cte6 Thx,,I did also before like that, but I am getting nonsense of results..

=SUMIFS($G$2:$G$6;$K$2:$K$6;L1)  is something similar that I wanted, but its just for 1 day..

Comment: @TerryW well, still nothing, cant figure it out - you said you might have suggest/solution? thx in advance

Comment: I got something actually using this:=SUMIFS($G:$G;$K:$K;L$1;E:E;$E2)
but it gives this:

ST
06:06:01
06:06:01
06:06:01
06:06:01
06:06:01

it is actually repetition of correct values but for all Dates that I have (5 same instances)..

I can "isolate" only one value (because the rest is the same)...any idea?

Comment: So, I think I managed this finally. Looks like making and filtering in Pivot Tables/Charts made exactly what I needed.

Comment: or you can make a new table with unique dates in one column and use the SUMIFS function to find the hours per system. Using Pivot Table is also one way of solving the issue without needing any formula.

Comment: @TerryW Thank you! I did it properly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the below snap to simplify your requirement.

please let me know if need to any more method.

If this not suits for your requirement you can create pivot table, which can be easier to get your result. The same have been explained by others in comment.

Formula For First Method: `=SUMIFS($E:$E,$H:$H,L$10,$A:$A,$K11)`

Formula For Second Method: `=SUMIFS($E:$E,$H:$H,K$21,$A:$A,$L19)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this will be taken also into consideration for further tasks. Important thing is, i did already on a bit other way, using Pivot and similar SUMIFs as you wrote!!!

Comment: Good !! Please Post The Answer What U Have Done. So that, others can get ideas who doesn't know these methods.

Answer (score 1):

My gratitude to all Users that helped me with an idea, what, where and how to look for my case. So I can post (for my purposes of course) some Infos for other that will be asking, eventually.

[image: SUMIFS]

Function used: `=SUMIFS($H:$H;$L:$L;M$1;D:D;$D2)` for both Systems in my case. And as you can notice in `Columns M and N` there are repetitive numbers (percentages). Usually, if you show that on charts it will give you `total SUM` or `Average` what actually is not what I asked. I needed `SUM per day per System`.

This was easy task, just remove duplicates and you are done.

[image: Remove duolicates - done]

Also, you can do using Pivot tables, but it is important to have "input" data good organised.

[image: Pivot 1]

[image: Pivot 2]

I dont need to explain Pivot I guess =)

The only calculation I did here is `% of time` using MOD function: `MOD(F3-F2;1)` where I calculated Time difference between 2nd date and 1st date. Then that "time" just converted to percentage. And good thing in Pivot, it recognizes it automatically as SUM, and you got exactly the same stuff as I wrote in first part using just SUMIFS and remove duplicates.

*Time difference is between those repetitive dates (2019-01-10) stated in first Picture in column D.

I am pretty sure there are many other ways, but I am happy that I got it this way(s), and always learned something new.

Thank you for your help!

Greets

Comment: Great! Well Tried!